# Is it possible to automatically enable bluetooth connection of user's device after launching my web application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I'm developing a web application (using node js and javascript) that needs to enable bluetooth connection of the device he/she is using before accessing the application. I've been looking for codes regarding to bluetooth enabling in web app but so far, I've only seen answers for android application which is not applicable to the language that I'm using.

When you lauch my web app in a browser, it will ask first a permission to a user to open/enable the bluetooth connection of his/her device then afterwards, she/he can access the application but if she/he cancel, the web app will be closed.

I hope my case is clear. I'm new to the web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enabling of Bluetooth is different depending on the device(iPhone, Android). It is possible to enable Bluetooth when a connection is made, but as I said the enabling differs from device to device. With all respect for you being new to web-developing, I suggest you take a look at more basic web-developing before you ask a question here. Also, this question involves other topics than node.js and Bluetooth.  I suggest you add the tags for every platform you want to be compatible with your app.

Good luck!

Comment: how about to know if the bluetooth of user's device(android) is on or off through my web app?